# Tensorflow object detection : Training job on google cloud fails

Tags: object, tensorflow, cloud, detection

I am getting this error when training my model on google cloud while trying to run Tensorflow Object detection

```
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement google-gax<0.16dev,>=0.15.7, but you'll have google-gax 0.12.5 which is incompatible.
```

any help how to fix it?

Comment: Please add the code/details to reproduce the error. It seems like some python dependency is missing.

Comment: I am running this as training :

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training training_job \
    --job-dir=gs://my_data_base/train \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    --runtime-version=1.4 \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://my_data_base/train \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://my_data_base/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config